# php filter words only works first word

Tags: php

```
<?php
function pfilter($text){
    $result = "";
    $word = "";
    $length = strlen($text);

    $file = fopen("words.txt", "r"); //contents of txt: cat dog (both on new lines)

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $result .= $text[$i];
        if($text[$i]!=' ') $word .= $text[$i];

        if(($text[$i] == ' ' || $i == $length-1) && $word!=' ' && $word!=''){
            while(!feof($file)){
                $line = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', fgets($file));

                if($line == $word){
                    $wlength = strlen($word);
                    $rlength = strlen($result);

                    for($j=1;$j<=$wlength;$j++){
                        $result[$rlength - $j - 1] = '*';
                    }

                }
            }

            $word = '';
        }

    }
    fclose($file);
    return $result;
}

echo pfilter("cat dog meow bark");
?>
```

Yes I know there is potentially a one liner that could do all of this. But I'm just confused as to why this isn't working, it should replace both cat and dog with ***, but only does cat in the beginning. There must be something I'm just not seeing here? $line and $word wont match up after the first word, but i've checked and they don't contain spaces

Comment: Since you never reset the pointer after you go through the file the first time, the second time through the loop, it's already hit `feof($file)`. You'd probably be better off pre-filling an array with the file data, then you can iterate through that each loop.

Comment: will you consider using different function such as preg_replace, explode, and file ?
(thanks aynber. this should be a comment, not an answer)